# From "Matrix" form to "Component" (tensor) form

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, tensor-calculus

Given

> $\omega=-\eta\omega^T\eta^{-1}=-\eta\omega^T\eta$,
>
> where $\eta$ is the usual Minkowski metric.

Is the following logic correct?:
$$
{\omega^{~\mu}}_{\nu}= -{\eta_{\varepsilon\nu}}{\left(\omega^T\right)_{\sigma}}^{~\varepsilon}~\eta^{~\mu\sigma}= -{\left(\omega^T\right)^{\mu}}_{~\nu}=-{\omega^{~\nu}}_{\mu}
$$

and so
$$
{\omega^{~\mu}}_{\nu}+{\omega^{~\nu}}_{\mu}=0 .
$$
I'm not sure I'm translating the equation into component form correctly, the manipulation of indices I'm (in principle) happier with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as you can see your indices don't match up. You must have an equation of the form $A^\mu{}_\nu = B^\mu{}_\nu$.

The correct way to do it is
$$
\omega^\mu{}_\nu = - \eta^{\mu\rho} ( \omega^T)_\rho{}^\sigma \eta_{\sigma\nu} 
$$
Note the way the indices are always adjacent since this is matrix multiplication. Next, we use 
$$
( \omega^T)_\rho{}^\sigma = \omega^\sigma{}_\rho
$$
Then,
$$
\omega^\mu{}_\nu = - \eta^{\mu\rho} \omega^\sigma{}_\rho \eta_{\sigma\nu}  = - \omega_\nu{}^\mu
$$
Thus, the correct equation is
$$
\omega^\mu{}_\nu  + \omega_\nu{}^\mu = 0 .
$$

Comment: Oh of course!! This makes sense now, thanks so much!